# English specific usage of "vicarious"

Tags: word-usage

The usage of the term  ***[vicarious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vicarious)*** meaning:

> - experienced as a result of watching, listening to, or reading about the activities of other people, rather than by doing the activities yourself:
>     *She took a vicarious pleasure in her friend's achievements*. 
>     (Cambridge Dictionary)

appears to have developed only in the English language. Its origin is from Latin ***vicar/vicarious*** which were used mainly in religious political contexts:

***[Vicar](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vicar&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (from Etymonline):

> - The original notion is of "earthly representative of God or Christ;" but also used in sense of "person acting as parish priest in place of a real parson" (early 14c.).

***[vicarious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vicarious&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - 1630s, "taking the place of another ***from Latin vicarius "that supplies a place; substituted, delegated,***" from vicis ".

the contemporary usage appears to be:

> - ***from 1690s as "done or experienced in place of another"*** (usually in reference to punishment, often of Christ); ***from 1929 as "experienced imaginatively through another.***"

This later usage appears to be English specific as it didn't develop in other languages like [French](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vicaire/81815), [Spanish](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/vicario), [Italian](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vicario.shtml) or  [German](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vikar), where it is still used only in relation to the position of religious or political figures.

Question:

Where does this usage originate from? Etymonline suggestion refers to a possible analogy with the punishment of Christ, actually a very common topic in many countries.

Can this usage be traced back to religious or political contexts specific only to the English history?

Comment: Wait... did you just convince two people who answered to delete their answers, both of which are exactly in the style that _you_ answer in? (cut and paste of references). In this case they both answer your question by restating definitions 'vicar = a representative (noun)' and the obviously very nearby 'vicarious - representative (adj)'. Maybe the question should be why all these other European languages _did not_ develop the metaphorical meaning.

Comment: @Mitch - I didn't convince anybody to do anything, the posts didn't even attempt to answer my questions and, if only English, out of all other European languages, developed that connotation, it may probably be for some specific historical/cultural reason. Note that the term has the same Latin origin for all languages.

Comment: It doesn’t detract from your good question, but in French there's [“vicariant/e”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vicariant) that extends beyond the original religious/political meaning to one similar to the 1630s meaning you cite (at least in biology/ecology/medicine). There’s also a 1954 literary usage of [“vicarial/e”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Vicarial) that even seems similar to the 1690s meaning at issue: “This human experience, authentic, yet imagined and *vicarial* (vicarious?), [that] represents a true broadening of life’s experiences, [and] of my experiences as a man.”

Comment: @PapaPoule - interesting, but would that use extent to common language  or is it just scientific or literal.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of French, but I would guess that the first one (vicariant/e) is scientific and that **this use** of "vicarial/e," in light of its fairly recent "appearance," might even be an "anglicism" (which would support your observations). All that is subject to confirmation by a native speaker, but I do know that when I try to use "vicarious/euse" or even "vicarieusement" (with my bad French accent, of course) when talking with my French wife in her language, she looks pitifully at me like I'm crazy (the same way she looks when I slip-up and use "entrée" to mean "main course.")

Comment: Looking for cultural reasons for things like this is probably unlikely to be fruitful. I suspect that they're usually just accidents of circumstance -- someone used the word metaphorically, and it became popular in that society. Prior to modern communications technology, such uses didn't spread easily.

Comment: This is just a guess of  mine, perhaps the adjective was employed as a criticism towards a (false) pope, an archbishop or a monarch claimed to be acting in God's will, but evidently was more concerned with secular trappings.

Comment: @Josh Is "Vicarious Love" an accurate translation of the title of this Spanish poetry form the 1600s https://books.google.com/books?id=usQ3DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT3&dq=%22vicarious+love%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd1tSFvJLSAhVIPiYKHShVCfgQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22vicarious%20love%22&f=false ?

Comment: @DavePhD - that looks like a title given in the English edition of that book. Consider that in other European languages there is no equivalent adjective and you need a sentence translate "vicarious".

Comment: I can’t pin it down, but it might have something to do w/the development of [different theories of Atonement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atonement_in_Christianity) & how protestant reformists developed their theories ([“Penal substitution,”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_substitution) aka“Vicarious repentance”) from Anselm of Canterbury’s [Satisfaction Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_theory_of_atonement) (where “satisfaction"="to make restitution" and not "gratification"). This "Canterbury Connection" & the importance of the Reformation in England might hold clues.

Comment: @PapaPoule - interesting theory, and thanks for understanding my question.

Comment: An English-Italian dictionary says "vicarious" adj. means "vicariale, di vacario" https://books.google.com/books?id=jfAPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA550&dq=italian+to+english+vicarious&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmuNHaopjSAhXI1CYKHZTlCwAQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=italian%20to%20english%20vicarious&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD - yes but that refers to the functions and activities of a vicar. Nothing like vicarious pleasure, love, etc. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/V/vicarious.shtml

Comment: @Josh This gives a Spanish example "A ellos se les enseñó el bautismo vicario para la remisión de los pecados " = "These were taught vicarious baptism for the remission of sins" http://www.spanishdict.com/examples/vicario There are numerous examples of "Bautismo vicario" for "vicarious baptism" https://www.lds.org/topics/proxy-baptism?lang=spa&old=true

Comment: This “thought” would only apply to the word’s extension/divergence from French, but “par procuration” is one of the ways of expressing this sense of “vicarious” in French & since [“Procuration”](http://www.finedictionary.com/Procuration.html) [already?] had a rather specific meaning in the Church of England, maybe English "needed" to use a word that didn’t conflict with that meaning of “procuration.” (this "need" could also perhaps help explain why English developed the contraction “proxy,” which has, in fact, been extended [via “by proxy”] to be nearly synonymous w/this sense of “vicarious.”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the exceptional use of "vicarious" in English, the answer must be in what was different in England as opposed to other places.
The first obvious place to look is The Church. And, practice in England did differ as to "vicars".
Before Henry VIII departed ways with the Roman Church, "vicar" was a much more common post in England than other countries. Vicars had become parish priests, and, today most parishes have either a Rector or Vicar as head. This is a matter of general knowledge, which can be researched easily enough, so no particular citation will be offered. This difference in England might have been part of the change in meaning of "vicarious", but other factors were probably more important.
*The Act of Supremacy(1534)* by Parliament, formally made Henry VIII the head of the Church of England [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Supremacy) . This was the consummation of other efforts to lessen the influence of The Pope on England.
However The Church did not change a great deal  in England by the removal of The Pope from supremacy. What changed the most was probably attitudes rather than practice. Church officials were now responsible to the Monarch, which in some eyes meant the Church and State were one.
Still, the general nature of church officials, including vicars, had not changed. But the attitudes of many in the general population seem to have evolved.
Many revolted against "The Church" whether headed by Pope or Monarch. Freewheeling Protestantism arose. England had a Civil War.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War)
From the various conflicts of the 17th Century religious diversity became general.
However, the vicar was still responsible for his parish and tithing.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithe). The Church had not let go.
For some time, "Vicar" and "vicarious" were terms in law [Law Dictionary, 1708](https://books.google.com/books?id=slpFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP316&lpg=PP316&dq=vicer%20church&source=bl&ots=b0bNZGBH5Y&sig=9jhKGz7W2TCtmLRTGIcXr-OK-DI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuwLaz35fSAhWFKyYKHSHXDv04ChDoAQhCMAg#v=onepage&q=vicer%20church&f=false) . But the most common legal use of "vicarious", *vicarious liability* did not seem to develop until end of the 19th Century.[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vicarious%20liability&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvicarious%20liability%3B%2Cc0).

Just the same *vicarious* seems to have have lost much of its religious sting in the 19th Century. Vicars and Rectors no longer be seen as King's publicans in robes after the *Commutation Act of* (1836)[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithe). The concept of "vicarious" may have moved away from The Church. This would have begun before the middle of the 19th Century[Universal Etymological Dictionary,1773](https://books.google.com/books?id=q05GAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP872&lpg=PP872&dq=vicar%20legal%20term&source=bl&ots=oYx60RPOAC&sig=quz4oGziRN0alc689xAYCkKXMeU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs8JaK45fSAhWGSCYKHQuUAOg4ChDoAQg9MAk#v=onepage&q=vicar%20legal%20term&f=false)
There seems no "smoking gun" to allow us to know when the term *vicarious* completely left The Church, and became almost entirely secular . However it is clear that the religious experiences of England in no way mirrored those of Continental Europe after Henry VIII. And, *vicarious* seems to have begun its secular journey with the decline of "The Church" beginning in the middle of the 16th Century.

Comment: Already by 1652 there is "Is it not a pleasant thing to behold a Sun? nay, to behold but a Candle, a deputed light? a vicarious light? the ape of a Sun-beame? ", http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A35416.0001.001/1:7?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1660;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=vicarious which isn't directly church related.

Comment: Thank you. I had some references that I thought too "iffy" to include.. The passage you cite may be fine as a non-church  meaning, but, two pages previous, the author uses the term " Candle of the Lord", and ,in fact, that term  "Candle of the Lord" was used many times previously in the work, and is always capitalized.  I cannot determine if "vicarious" is not there in a religious sense.

Comment: I think authors would capitalize many words back then.  For example Star, Comet, Jewel, Hypocrite, Epitomize, Knight, Bodies, Corporeal, Chaos, Lamp, Reason, Motions, Operations and Nature are all capitalized on that page.

Comment: I agree. In fact, at times , some would treat English nouns much as German treats nouns today.. However this author does not do that.. The capitals seem to separate important concepts from mundane things.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting historical summary. So, if I understand correctly, you are saying that the rise of Anglicanism is somehow resposible for a more active and widespread usage of vicarious.

Comment: Not exactly. The peculiar nature of "The Church" in England, even before the split with Rome had made  "vicar" a much more used term in England. The establishment of vicars as parish  priests, making the term much more familiar to the general population than in other countries began long before Henry VIII.. ..but it was vicars serving the Church of England  holding responsibility for both  Church and State  that may have started turning the term "vicar" from a strictly church use. The more general use of "vicar" in  England was critical, and that came before the break with Rome.

Comment: In 1685 Robert Boyle of chemistry fame (Boyle's Law) used the term "vicarious springs" for the power that made onions, potatoes, etc. grow without soil or water, as if spring had arrived.  http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?didno=A28982.0001.001;firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=full+text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=occur;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;q1=vicarious+springs

Answer (score 4):

According to a University of Notre Dame [Latin to English dictionary](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=vicarium), there are 3 Latin adjective forms of the word:

> vicarius, vicaria, vicarium

and the adjective meaning is:

> substitute; substituted; vicarious; supplying the place of someone/something

There is an entry for "vicarius" in the 1538 [dictionary of syr Thomas Eliot knight](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A21313.0001.001/1:7?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=vicarius):

> Vicarius, a, um,
>   that whiche is in the steede or place of an other. Also the seruaunte of hym, whiche is a seruant

The earliest English uses of "vicarious" are in the 1637 book [Dispute against the English Popish Ceremonies](https://archive.org/stream/dispsten00gill#page/74/mode/2up/search/vicarious):

page 71:

> but also looke upon it as an Image of Christ, or as a **vicarious** signe of Christ standing there in Christs stead

page 74:

> The Elements are actually Images and **vicarious** Signes standing in Christs Stead

A 1661 Dictionary [Glossographia, or, A dictionary interpreting all such hard words of whatsoever language now used in our refined English tongue with etymologies](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A28464.0001.001/1:7?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=vicarious) has the definition:

> **Vicarious**(vicarius) that is in stead or place of another, that supplies another mans room, and **takes pains for him**; as an under-servant, or Vicar.

(so already there is some evidence of the experiencing punishment for another meaning)

A transition to the next meaning "done or experienced in place of another (usually in reference to punishment, often of Christ)" can also be seen in the 1669 [A brief declaration and vindication of the doctrine of the Trinity as also of the person and satisfaction of Christ](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A53669.0001.001/1:8?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=vicarious):

> But in things *criminal*, the guilty person himself, being firstly, immediately and intentionally under the Obligation unto punishment, when there is introduced by *compact*, a ***vicarious*** solution in the substitution of another to suffer, though he suffer the *same absolutely* which those should have done for whom he suffers; yet because of the *Acceptation* of his person to suffer, which might have been refused, and could not be admitted, without some *Relaxation of the Law*, Deliverance of the guilty persons cannot ensue *ipso facto*, but by the intervention of the Terms fixed on in the Covenant or Agreement for an admittance of the substitution.

Also clearly the 22 October 1669 sermon [The waters of Marah sweetned](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A52175.0001.001/1:2?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=vicarious) shows such a meaning:

> The Death and Blood of Christ was **Vicarious**, instead of many. Many deaths were summed up in his one death. He was offered upon the Cross, to bear the sins of many.

Another early example of the meaning "experienced in place of another" is in the 1675 [Primitive Christianity](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?didno=A31421.0001.001;firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=full%20text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;q1=vicarious)

> who was baptized for him in his stead, whence Tertullian calls it a **vicarious** Baptism

Here, "vicarious baptism" is a translation of the Latin *[Vicarium Baptisma](https://books.google.com/books?id=AfnbwrrbXvEC&pg=PA671&lpg=PA671&dq=%22vicarium%20baptisma%22&source=bl&ots=-iY8dJK8FT&sig=CPrq70fJ8mMJHqSTSvnsEfSqocU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9xPKkgZjSAhVGZCYKHaWrDgoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22vicarium%20baptisma%22&f=false)*.

The usage "experienced imaginatively through another" is older than 1929.

The 1856 [Melborne Punch](https://books.google.com/books?id=W-U-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA148&dq=%22vicarious%20enjoyment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgqaWlspLSAhVE2yYKHZn4BDQQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=%22vicarious%20enjoyment%22&f=false) says:

> We doubt not that the writer of the above paragraph resembles *Midas* in more ways than one, but really we cannot be content with the **vicarious enjoyment of a joke**.

The 1859 [The emotions and the will](https://books.google.com/books?id=6DQCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22enjoyment%20is%20sought%20in%20gratifying%20the%20wishes%20and%20identifying%20oneself%20with%20the%20interests%20of%20a%20second%20individuality%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM8N7VtpLSAhXG2yYKHTQ8DIUQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22enjoyment%20is%20sought%20in%20gratifying%20the%20wishes%20and%20identifying%20oneself%20with%20the%20interests%20of%20a%20second%20individuality%22&f=false) says:

> The life of affection is vicarious; enjoyment is sought in gratifying the wishes and identifying oneself with the interests of a second individuality.

The 10 October 1863 [Saturday Review](https://books.google.com/books?id=r2MwAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA482&dq=%22luxuries;%20nay,%20there%20are%20ladies%20who%20are%20said%20to%20enjoy%20the%20vicarious%20pleasure%20of%20ordering%20other%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4rN74tZLSAhWF7CYKHYS_BpMQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22luxuries%3B%20nay%2C%20there%20are%20ladies%20who%20are%20said%20to%20enjoy%20the%20vicarious%20pleasure%20of%20ordering%20other%20%22&f=false) says:

> To furnish another person's house with upholstery which you do not pay for, to select a library which is not followed by the inevitable bill, are special luxuries; nay, there are ladies who are said to enjoy **the vicarious pleasure of ordering other ladies' bonnets**, and selecting the treasures of Waterloo House for the adornment of rival charms.

The 1864 [Doctor Jacob](https://books.google.com/books?id=owwCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22vicarious%20pleasure%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqp83bsZLSAhXEOiYKHQW9D4oQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22vicarious%20pleasure%22&f=false) says:

> He had given up his balcony to the Paulus family, and **enjoyed a vicarious pleasure in the sight of the enraptured young faces around him**.

The 1874 [The Century, Volume 8](https://books.google.com/books?id=J8tZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA598&dq=%22vicarious%20pleasure%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlz6bGsJLSAhVLZSYKHWzDDdkQ6AEISzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22vicarious%20pleasure%22&f=false) says:

> Your true English writer, it would seem, **takes a vicarious pleasure in feasting his characters**.

The 1874 The [Aldine: The Art Journal of America](https://www.google.com/search?q=vicariously&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1880%2Ccd_max%3A1920&tbm=bks#q=%22vicariously%20enjoying%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks) says:

> ... on another and longer bench, under the same noble shade, sat a row of old people, male and female, thus **vicariously enjoying the sports in which they could no longer take part to advantage** ...

Overall, by searching for phrases such as "vicarious enjoyment" and "vicarious pleasure" it can be seen that the "experienced imaginatively through another" usage became prevalent around the mid 1800s.

Comment: Interesting, could it be that these "vicarious" experiences of pleasure and enjoyment were originally referred to religious experiences? Could they refer to old church prayers for instance? from which the more common usage later?

Comment: @Josh there is a somewhat similar religious usage from 1787 "We frequently read of vicarious suffering in the jewish gospel, but not of vicarious obedience, and vicarious love." https://books.google.com/books?id=VRhXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA195&dq=vicarious+love&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH0OKi0ZLSAhXE2SYKHRsICsAQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=vicarious%20love&f=false

Comment: @Josh and the phrase "vicarious atonement" was used back to at least 1723 "a perversion of the original system of vicarious atonement" https://books.google.com/books?id=BZ8_AQAAMAAJ&q=%22vicarious+atonement%22&dq=%22vicarious+atonement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-t7H1JLSAhVBSyYKHSFZBLAQ6AEIKDAC and "the Druids might admit the doctrine of vicarious atonement by human sacrifices" https://books.google.com/books?id=QgUGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22vicarious+atonement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn-t7H1JLSAhVBSyYKHSFZBLAQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22vicarious%20atonement%22&f=false

Comment: @Josh going from "vicarious atonement" to "vicarious enjoyment" doesn't seem like a big leap.

Comment: Yes, the "vicarious atonement"  usage is close to the 1690 reference suggested by etymonline. This idiomatic usage most likely originated in religious writings and preaches IMO.

Comment: @Josh what about the 1850 "Active Sympathy therefore we define to be the power of entering into the emotions of a fellow being and bearing them with him *vicariously*" (italics in original)  https://books.google.com/books?id=bKxWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA193&dq=%22vicariously%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihiP_SqZfSAhXDSSYKHYY1B-oQ6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=%22vicariously%22&f=false Do you think that is starting to cross over into the "experienced imaginatively through another" meaning?

Comment: Very nice findings, which predate its idiomatic usage of at least 50 years compared to Etymonline suggestion.

Comment: @Josh Where the 1675 source says "whence Tertullian calls it a vicarious Baptism", it is a translation of "vicarium baptisma", https://books.google.com/books?id=BRBTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA258&dq=%22vivarium+baptisma%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5rObJ_ZfSAhXHOCYKHVFDBH8Q6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22vivarium%20baptisma%22&f=false.

Comment: Yes, the expression *bautismo vicario* does exist, but *vicario* in Spanish cannot be used as in English. http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/vicarious -

Answer (score 0):

From **Online Etymology Dictionary** (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vicarious)

**vicarious (adj)**

1630s, "taking the place of another," from Latin vicarius "that supplies a place; substituted, delegated," from vicis "a change, exchange, interchange; succession, alternation, substitution," from PIE root *weik- (4) "to bend, wind" (source also of Sanskrit visti "changing, changeable;" Old English wician "to give way, yield," wice "wych elm;" Old Norse vikja "to bend, turn;" Swedish viker "willow twig, wand;" German wechsel "change").

From 1690s as "done or experienced in place of another" (usually in reference to punishment, often of Christ); from 1929 as "experienced imaginatively through another." Related: Vicariously.

From **Merriam Webster:**

If you act in someone’s stead, you take his or her place, at least temporarily. The oldest meaning of "vicarious," which was first recorded in 1637, is "serving in someone or something’s stead." The word vicarious derives from the Latin noun vicis, which means "change," "alternation," or "stead." "Vicis" is also the source of the English prefix vice- (as in "vice president"), meaning "one that takes the place of."
Origin and Etymology of vicarious

Latin vicarius, from vicis change, alternation, stead.

**First Known Use: 1637**

Comment: Thanks, but in what way does this answer my question?